# How to check whether one branch is an ancestor of the other in Git

Tags: git

I have to Git branches A and B. How to check whether A is an ancestor of B, or vice versa?

`git merge-base` does give the common ancestor. However I'd like to know whether there are even better solutions.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by a branch being an ancestor of another - branches are just pointers to commits, so it makes more sense to think of commits being ancestors of other commits or not. But perhaps `git branch --contains` is what you are looking for (`git help branch` for more information)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor A B
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
   # it's an ancestor
else
   # it's not an ancestor
fi
```

This is obviously working on the commits that the branches point to.  Git doesn't really track branch lineage the way something like Clearcase does though, so it's quite possible that you could have had A first, then branched off B, and then as a result of some merging end up with B as an ancestor to A.